# Easiest way to switch git branches

Tags: command-line, autocompletion, git, plugin-fugitive

Right now I'm using fugitive to manage almost everything git related, but I can't find a good workflow to quickly visualize and switch between available branches.

I can do `:Git checkout <branch-name>`, the problem is that it autocompletes both file names and branches, and I'd prefer a branch list.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To summarize the answers, here are the ways to accomplish this:

### Vanilla Terminal Vim in a shell with job control

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in normal mode will drop you back in to the shell and suspend Vim. After executing your `git checkout [branchname]`, run the `fg` builtin to return to the suspended Vim which will also force Vim to refresh (`:help timestamp`).

It is also noteworthy that the `:checktime` command in Vim will perform a buffer scan to see what filesystem changes there have been. See `:help :checktime` for more info.

In vim 8, you can use `:terminal` to start a shell, or `:terminal git checkout [branchname]` to run one command. Neither will automatically `:checktime`.

### Vanilla GUI Vim

Some gvim implementations will have `:shell` support which will open a shell inside of Vim using a dumb terminal. However it may be easier to just type:

```
:!git checkout [branchname]
```

This will execute the command without having to open a new shell prompt. (This option is also usable in the terminal Vim).

### vim-fugitive

[plugin-fugitive](/questions/tagged/plugin-fugitive) is a plugin that allows you to use Git from within Vim. The command would be:

```
:Git checkout [branchname]
```

### vim-merginal

[vim-merginal](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal) is a plugin that uses [plugin-fugitive](/questions/tagged/plugin-fugitive) and provides a user friendly-ish interface.

1. Type `:Merginal`.
2. Move cursor to the branch you want.
3. Type `cc` to check out that branch.

Comment: Awesome answer. `vim-merginal` is what I was looking for.

Comment: I like the `ctrl-z` because it auto loads the files. Co-workers like to have a tmux window for the command line and one for vim but when they do a checkout or merge when they return to vim they have to go to each open file and `:e!` each time. (`:bufdo e`) which is a pain to remember. Instead it is easier to `ctrl-z` then when `fg` happens Vim performs the `:e` auto-magically.

Comment: I Another nice fugitive extension you could add to the list: https://github.com/sodapopcan/vim-twiggy

Answer (score 13):

Use the [vim-merginal](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal) plugin ([fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) extension). It offers interactive TUI for:

- **Viewing the list of branches**
- **Checking out branches from that list**
- Creating new branches
- Deleting branches
- Merging branches
- Rebasing branches
- Solving merge conflicts
- Interacting with remotes(pulling, pushing, fetching, tracking)
- Diffing against other branches
- Renaming branches
- Viewing git history for branches

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You should embrace your terminal. If you use <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>, it will background Vim (or whichever process you are currently running), then you can run any commands you want, the `fg` to bring the process back to the foreground:

```
<CTRL-Z>
git checkout <tab>
fg
```

Comment: ... and when using GVim?

Comment: `:shell` is the way to go or alt tabbing in to your other favorite terminal emulator

Comment: I always like `!git checkout [branchname]`

Answer (score 7):

The fugitive `Git checkout <branch>` has a downside that it doesn't autocomplete the branch name. Using [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) I've created this command:

```
function! s:changebranch(branch) 
    execute 'Git checkout' . a:branch
    call feedkeys("i")
endfunction

command! -bang Gbranch call fzf#run({
            \ 'source': 'git branch -a --no-color | grep -v "^\* " ', 
            \ 'sink': function('s:changebranch')
            \ })
```

hope you find it useful

Answer (score 5):

Ever since [this commit in Jul 2019](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commit/7bfce97480038c93088664c50cc78593ce05645f), this has been possible using Git fugitive only.

Type `:G branch` will open a split buffer with all the branches in a list. Place your cursor on the branch and press `coo` to checkout the branch.

From `:h fugitive_co`

```
Checkout/branch mappings ~

coo                     Check out the commit under the cursor.

cb<Space>               Populate command line with ":G branch ".

co<Space>               Populate command line with ":G checkout ".

cb?                     Show this help.
co?
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @kubek2k is so phenomenal.  That solution is better than I could have imagined and implemented in in less lines of code that I could have imaged.  It opened the door to help me understand the powerful personalization use of 'fzf'.

I have slightly modified it to additionally provide:

1. Makes use of fugitive to get the refs instead of the command line, (better support for windows)
2. List tags along with branches

Here is the slight modification:

```
function! s:gitCheckoutRef(ref) 
    execute('Git checkout ' . a:ref)
    " call feedkeys("i")
endfunction
function! s:gitListRefs()
   let l:refs = execute("Git for-each-ref --format='\\%(refname:short)'")
   return split(l:refs,'\r\n*')[1:] "jump past the first line which is the git command
endfunction
command! -bang Gbranch call fzf#run({ 'source': s:gitListRefs(), 'sink': function('s:gitCheckoutRef'), 'dir':expand('%:p:h') })
```

Comment: That sounds like a nice addition. However this doesn't work for me (no results are shown after `:Gbranch`) whereas kubek2k solution does work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this FZF plugin that adds a `GBranches` command to browse your repo.

https://github.com/stsewd/fzf-checkout.vim

Edit:

I'm now using https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim to switch git branches:
`:Telescope git_branches<CR>`